# How can I start a new village in Minecraft Comes Alive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

I am running 1.7.10 with Minecraft Comes Alive 4.1.5 which from what I read replaces the vanilla villages with more interaction and the option to marry and start a family. In vanilla Minecraft, to start a new village I used [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Village_mechanics) and used the [Apartment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Village_mechanics#Apartment) as the house.

What I would like to know is how I can start a new village in Minecraft Comes Alive? Is it different than what it is in Vanilla?

Answer (score 1):

- You need some valid housing as described on the [village mechanics](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Village_mechanics) page. This is the same in either version.
- You need some villagers there to make it a village. In vanilla this usually involved converting zombies or pushing or carting a villager a long way. In MCP it's easy because you can just right click a villager and ask them to follow you. There is also an option to set a villager's home to the room you are currently standing in, so they don't just wander back to where you found them.
- To expand a village you either need story progression on(the default) or to use matchmaker's rings. Alternately you could just populate the village with your own dynasty.

This should be clearer if you read up on the mechanics of the mod on the radix-shock page (http://www.radix-shock.com/mca--how-to-play.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but I'll do my best

- Villages generate the same
- Villagers will change over if in already explored villages
- They will for the most part behave like normal villagers so if you build a city/town ( to the village standards) they will inhabit it
- I don't know what you mean by "apartment" but if it is a building designed for villagers they will live in and breed ( if there are enough doors) in it

I hope that answers you question.